# AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'RemovedIn20Warning'

Tags: python, pytest, python-poetry

I am trying to run tests and setting certain types of warnings as errors. No matter which warning I set to be treated in pytest.ini I get same exception, just the type changes. What do I need to do to get passed this exception?

```
ERROR: while parsing the following warning configuration:

  error::RemovedIn20Warning

This error occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/edv/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-gX2kb1zU-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1761, in parse_warning_filter
    category: Type[Warning] = _resolve_warning_category(category_)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/edv/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/api-gX2kb1zU-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1800, in _resolve_warning_category
    cat = getattr(m, klass)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'RemovedIn20Warning'
```

pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    always::DeprecationWarning
    #ignore::pytest.PytestAssertRewriteWarning
    #ignore::pluggy.PluggyTeardownRaisedWarning
    #ignore::PytestUnknownMarkWarning
    #ignore::PydanticDeprecatedSince20
    #ignore::PytestAssertRewriteWarning
    ignore:.*Setting backref.*
    error::RemovedIn20Warning
```

Comment: You know how you wrote `pytest.PytestAssertRewriteWarning`, instead of just `PytestAssertRewriteWarning`, because that warning class lives in the `pytest` package namespace instead of being a built-in? You forgot to do the same thing for other non-built-in warnings.

Comment: @user2357112 It does not matter, even for that one it throws same error. I tried exc.RemovedIn20Warning it still throws.

Comment: It's from `sqlalchemy.exc`, not `exc`.